# How to represent directed graph with multiple parents?

Tags: database-design, hierarchy

http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html provides an algorithm for inserting and deleting from a Closure Table.

I'd like to model a similar data structure, except that nodes may have multiple parents.

Given:

[image: Graph #1]

If we remove `[B, C]` I expect to end up with:

[image: Graph #2]

and if we remove node `B` I expect to end up with:

[image: Graph #3]

However, if you use the author's algorithm for removing links or nodes you will notice that it tags `[D, C, 1]` for deletion, which is undesirable.

### What I've tried so far

I have tried adapting the original data structure by adding a `references` column that indicates how many ways there are to travel between two nodes. In the above example, you can travel from `A` to `C` either through `B` or through `D`. The idea would have been that when `B` gets removed, the path from `A` to `C` gets kept and the reference count decreases from 2 to 1. It was nice in theory, but I couldn't figure out how to get the implementation working and now I wonder if it's at all possible (the data structure might not contain enough information to figure out which rows to remove).

### What I'm asking

How would you adapt Closure Tables to support multiple parents? What alternative data structures would you recommend? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/14731 contains an exaustive list of such data structures, but it's not clear which ones support (or are best for) multiple parents.

Comment: So, what have you tried? And what is the `references` column?

Comment: I don't believe one _would_ adapt closure tables in your scenario.  Closure tables are good for many tree based applications, but this question alludes to a much less restrictive type of DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).  This is a topic which might be suitable for a Masters thesis and like so many things when it comes to databases, an optimal solution will heavily rely on your exact, specific use case. [This](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o) might help you get started.

Comment: Which db software?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, H2 and PostgreSQL though obviously I prefer a DB-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 3):

Usually create a nodes table and a relationships table.  Directed graphs are't really hierarchical and they can have loops which makes querying harder.  But if you think of a DAG as being a generalised tree (I.e. a tree that allows multiple parents but is still strictly hierarchical) and a directed graph as being a generalised DAG (i.e. like a DAG but not strictly hierarchical) things get easier.

So for a very simple, PostgreSQL solution we might do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
    id serial primary key,
    payload jsonb not null
);

CREATE TABLE relationship (
    id serial primary key,
    relationship_type text not null,
    from_node int references node(id) not null,
    to_node int references node(id) not null,
    payload jsonb not null
);
```

Then you can query something like this:

```
with recursive dg as (
    select n.id as node_id, null::Int as parent, array[n.id] as path
      from node n
    union all
    select to_node, from_node, path || to_node
      FROM relationship
      JOIN dg on dg.node_id = from_node AND NOT from_node = ANY(path)
)
select * from dg;
```